# mysqli_error() caused by query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the query below of which works perfectly fine in phpMyAdmin given that I replace the PHP variables with actual values. When this query is run in my PHP code I end up with the error:

**Warning**:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **/Applications/AMPPS/www/resources/text/php/get_promoted.php** on line **58**

Line 58:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS (SELECT address_id, address,
        city, state_province, zip_post,
        latitude, longitude, distance
  FROM (
 SELECT z.address_id,
        z.address,
        z.city,
        z.state_province,
        z.zip_post,
        z.latitude, z.longitude,
        p.radius,
        p.distance_unit
                 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                 * COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
                 * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.longitude))
                 + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(z.latitude)))) AS distance
  FROM address AS z
  JOIN (   
        SELECT " . $_SESSION['address']['latitude'] . " AS latpoint, " . $_SESSION['address']['longitude'] . " AS longpoint,
                5.0 AS radius,      69.055 AS distance_unit
    ) AS p ON 1=1
  WHERE z.latitude
     BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
         AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
    AND z.longitude
     BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
         AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
 ) AS d 
 WHERE distance <= radius 
 ORDER BY distance);
 SELECT 
    name AS restaurant, 
    description AS type, 
    address, 
    city, 
    state_province AS county, 
    zip_post AS post,
    ROUND(AVG(rating),0) AS avg_rating,
    ROUND(distance,2) AS distance,
    logo,
    prom.date_created AS promotion_expiry,
    value AS promotion_cost
  FROM temp AS addr
 INNER JOIN restaurant_address AS rest_addr
    ON addr.address_id=rest_addr.address_id
 INNER JOIN restaurant AS rest
    ON rest_addr.restaurant_id=rest.restaurant_id 
 INNER JOIN promotion AS prom
    ON prom.restaurant_id=rest.restaurant_id
 INNER JOIN review AS rev
    ON rest.restaurant_id=rev.restaurant_id
 WHERE distance<delivery_radius GROUP BY restaurant ORDER BY promotion_cost DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Any idea as to what could be causing this? I have ruled out the idea of my mysqli_connect() not working by putting in a simple select statement and it works just fine.

Comment: Do you close the connection prior to this? `$con` is `null` and not an object, that's the problem here. The query has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Nope no closure and I've replaced the query with a simpler one and it worked so I have no idea whats going on

Comment: With the original query, what is `var_dump($con);` just before line 58?

Comment: Placing it just before the query is run returns an object with things like client info, client version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really get any help from anyone and the answer was pretty simple.

Use **mysqli_multi_query** instead of **mysqli_query**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against using `mysqli_multi_query()`. There's no benefit from using it, and it risks a whole new class of SQL injection vulnerabilities:

[image: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png]

Instead, you should execute one SQL statement per call to `mysqli_query()`. Then the "Bobby Tables" scenario *can't* occur.

There's no reason you need to do multiple queries in a single call.

You might think that putting the queries together in a single call is necessary to use the temporary table in the SELECT query. This is not true—you can use the temporary table in subsequent queries, as long as you use the same database session.

Comment: The query above only uses data that is already sanitized and put into the database but I will implement an alternative to multi query, thanks!